# std::get_deleter on std::shared_ptr initialized with std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, stdbind

Let's say I have this code:

```
class BaseObject
{
public:
    virtual void OnDestroy() {}
};
template <typename T>
struct myArrayDeleter
{
    void operator()(T *p, std::size_t count)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            static_cast<BaseObject*>((void*)(int(p) + sizeof(T) * i))->OnDestroy();
        }
        delete [] p;
    }
};
```

And let's assume that it works as intended (it's a simplified version, written now without the check but basically you know what this code should do).
With this part I don't have a problem. However, check this out:

```
class AActor
    : public BaseObject
{
public:
    virtual void OnDestroy() override
    {
        // some code here
    }
};

template <typename T>
class SimplifiedHolder
{
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_shared;
    std::size_t m_size;
public:
    // Some not important code here

    // WE ASSUME HERE THAT IT ALWAYS HOLDS ARRAY
    // sizeOfArray always > 1
    template <typename U>
    SimplifiedHolder(U *ptr, std::size_t sizeOfArray)
        : m_size(sizeOfArray)
    {
        m_shared = std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr,
                           std::bind(&myArrayDeleter<U>(), std::placeholders::_1, m_size));
    }

    // And now as we initialize our shared_ptr with template
    // we can check if it is exactly of type "U"
    template <typename U>
    bool IsExactlyOfType()
    {
        if(!m_shared)
            return false;

        return ((void*)std::get_deleter<myArrayDeleter<U>>(m_shared)) != nullptr;
    }
};
```

However, the method `IsExactlyOfType` isn't working. That's because I initialized `shared_ptr` with `std::bind`. `std::get_deleter` always returns `nullptr` because the wrong type is specified in the template. I don't know what type to pass. I tried also with non-array code in which `myDeleter` is a functor with only one argument and it works perfectly with code like this:

```
template <typename U>
bool IsExactlyOfType()
{
     if(!m_shared)
         return false;

     return ((void*)std::get_deleter<myDeleter<U>>(m_shared) != nullptr;
}
```

I know I could go with `typeid(U) == typeid(*m_shared.get())` but this is not what I want. I have much more complicated code and in that case only this method is good.

Can a more experienced programmer tell me what type to specify to `std::get_deleter`?

Comment: In your deleter, what if a pointer can't fit in an `int`? If `sizeof(T*) > sizeof(int)`? Why not simply use `&p[i]`?

Comment: Well as I wrote its quite more complicated in the code, and it basically works as intended and that is not the point here. The point is I don't know which type to specify for std::get_deleter.

Comment: I still hope you're not using a cast such as `int(p)` in your real code. It ***will*** break on just about all 64-bit systems.

Comment: Good point, I will keep this in mind, thanks.

Comment: If your deleter (or anything else for that matter) is `ABC<XYZ>(MNPQR)` then its type is `decltype(ABC<XYZ>(MNPQR))`, no more, no less. Thus, `decltype(std::bind(&myArrayDeleter<U>(), std::placeholders::_1, m_size))`

Comment: I thought that would work but unluckily it doesn't. Just returning nullptr again...

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/VZOO91813)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that compiler wasn't translating decltype correctly. I tried to get deleter immediately after initializing shared_ptr and it worked. However the same decltype in function was generating slightly other type. I checked it in debugger and it generated this results:

In constructor:

```
std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,grim::impl::TObjectArrayDeleter<APlayer>,std::_Ph<1> const &,unsigned int &> &
```

In function:

```
std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,grim::impl::TObjectArrayDeleter<APlayer>,std::_Ph<1> const &,unsigned int const &> *
```

Take a look at the end - it appended additional const. I needed to change it manually, so now my code looks like this:

```
using D = std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,grim::impl::TObjectArrayDeleter<U>,
                       std::_Ph<1> const &,unsigned int &>;

return ((void*)std::get_deleter<D>(m_shared)) != nullptr;
```